# when I change the button caption, the button size will be also changed in android

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

I have some buttons. for example 15 . 3*5 (3 in row and 5 in column) every 3 buttons exist in one horizontal linear layout and weight of every one is 1 . but I don't know why when I change the button caption, the button size will be also changed in android.
please help me. thanks

Comment: In order to help others understand your issue, please post a sample of code,  the outputs of any logs (e.g. LogCat) or something to demonstrate a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here it's my code:

```
 <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnGeneral_surgery"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="120dp"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:background="@drawable/mybtn"
                 android:drawableTop="@drawable/general_surgery"
                 android:text="btnGeneral_surgery"
                 android:textColor="@color/greenwhatsup"
                 android:textSize="15sp" />

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnOtolaryngology"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="120dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:background="@drawable/mybtn"
                 android:drawableTop="@drawable/otolaryngology"
                 android:text="btnOtolaryngology_Profesional"
                 android:textColor="@color/greenwhatsup"
                 android:textSize="12sp" />

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnObstetrics"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="120dp"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:background="@drawable/mybtn"
                 android:drawableTop="@drawable/obstetrics"
                 android:text="btnObstetrics"
                 android:textColor="@color/greenwhatsup"
                 android:textSize="15sp" />
         </LinearLayout>
```

I think maybe because of different sizes of text, size of buttons will be change.

Comment: Can anybody help me?!